# ag without PATH parameter vs. ag with PATH parameter

Tags: ag

If I call `ag "SomeTest" ~/foo` I get no result, while `cd ~/foo; ag "SomeTest"` lists the expected result. How comes?

Comment: Weird. Is this with the same session and user?

Comment: Yes. It's ag version 0.30.0 running in a Debian-wheezy-based LinuxContainer, same user, same shell.

Comment: is there any vcs ignores in play here? Add the -U flag to check. Is the foo directory compressed? Add the -z flag to check.

Comment: Thx for the hints. After having updated my system I can't reproduce it anymore, however.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the file you're searching for is in a symbolically linked directory, which ag does not follow unless you instruct to with the -f flag. For example:

```
$< /tmp/foo
test
$ls -l /tmp/foo
lrwxr-xr-x  1 gregory  wheel  18B Jan 16 01:00 /tmp/foo -> /Users/gregory/foo
$ag test ./tmp
$ag -f test ./tmp
tmp/foo
1:test
```